# How to align center a circular progress bar in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement a circular progress bar in a login form using material UI. Which can not be aligned in the center position: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpRvQ.jpg)

```js
 {isLoading && <CircularProgress />}
          {user?.email && (
            <Alert severity="success">
              Your Registration Created Successfully
            </Alert>
          )}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really related to material UI, just a general styling issue / how to position and style your components.
Just put your logic into a parent `div` (or any custom component) and use flexbox to center vertically and horizontally. Of course your parent `div` needs to be at the height, width, position etc how you need it to fit in your app.

Here an inline React example

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        // do your styles depending on your needs.
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      {  
        // content to center here 
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```